# Is it secure to seed PRNGs with the sequences from CSPRNG?

Tags: java, security, random, prng

`java.security.SecureRandom` besides others has two methods: `generateSeed(int numBytes)` and `nextBytes(byte[] bytes)`. The former gets entropy from the external source and is less predictable but slower, the latter uses PRNG sequence and is more predictable but much faster.

I want to have a single `java.security.SecureRandom` to seed a number of *MersenneTwisterFast* PRNGs, and my question is whether it is secure enough to seed them with `nextBytes` as long as `SecureRandom` has been seeded in a secure manner in the first place?

Comment: You may get better answers to this question if you ask it at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also: secure enough for what application?

Comment: Oh, blimey, didn't know about that, thank you! The application is fun casino, no real money whatsoever.

Comment: In case anyone interested, here is the clone of this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52300/how-secure-is-to-seed-prngs-with-the-sequences-from-csprng

Comment: OP has asked the question on Security.SE instead: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52300/how-secure-is-to-seed-prngs-with-the-sequences-from-csprng